# No graph grids using plotyy

Tags: plot, octave

I'm doing a code to read a csv file and draw two graphs in the same plot.

It mostly works, but I'm not able to enable 'xgrid' and 'ygrid'. I've tried several approaches but the result is always the same, there is no grid at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Here the code:

```
clear();
close all;

#Package to load csv files
pkg load io;

#conv from MJD to JD
function JD = fromMJDtoJD(MJD)
  JD = (MJD + 2400000.5);
endfunction

#Conv from JD to UTC
function Datte = fromJDtoUTC(JD)
   ZeroJD  = datenum (-4713,11,24,12,0,0);
   Days = ZeroJD + JD ;
   Datte = datevec(Days);
endfunction

#Conv from MJD to UTC
function UTCDate = fromMJDtoUTC(MJD)
  UTCDate = fromJDtoUTC(fromMJDtoJD(MJD));
endfunction


#Load csv file
[nombreFicheroCSV, pathFicheroCSV]=uigetfile("*.csv");
nombreCompletoCSV = fullfile (pathFicheroCSV, nombreFicheroCSV);
ficheroCSV=csv2cell(nombreCompletoCSV, ",");

#gets columns data (without header, first row)
MJD_days = cell2mat(ficheroCSV(2:end,1));
Pos_cts = cell2mat(ficheroCSV (2:end,2));
Error_cts = cell2mat(ficheroCSV (2:end,3));
Current_ma = cell2mat(ficheroCSV (2:end,4));
RDY = ficheroCSV (2:end,5);
ENA = ficheroCSV (2:end,6);
HOK = ficheroCSV (2:end,7);
IMV = ficheroCSV (2:end,8);
HTD = ficheroCSV (2:end,9);
BRK = ficheroCSV (2:end,10);

#conv MJD column from MJD to UTC using the custom function
[nr,nc]=size(MJD_days);
timeFormat = 'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS';
for f = 1:nr,
  aux = datestr(fromMJDtoUTC(MJD_days(f)));
  UTC_days (f)= datenum(aux,timeFormat);
end

#row to column
UTC_days=UTC_days';

%Plot axis
[ax,h1,h2]=plotyy(UTC_days,Current_ma,UTC_days,Pos_cts);

set(h1,'color','g','Marker','.');
set(h2,'color','r','Marker','.')

datetick(ax(1),'x',timeFormat,'keepticks');
datetick(ax(2),'x',timeFormat,'keepticks');

%Def x grid (same in both axes)
xticks = (max(UTC_days)- min(UTC_days))/10;
set(ax(1),'xtick',min(UTC_days):xticks:max(UTC_days));
set(ax(2),'xtick',min(UTC_days):xticks:max(UTC_days));
set (ax(1),'xgrid','on');
set (ax(2),'xgrid','on');

%Def y grid (not the same in both axes)
yticks1 = (max(Current_ma)- min(Current_ma))/10;
yticks2 = (max(Pos_cts)- min(Pos_cts))/10;
set(ax(1),'ytick',min(Current_ma):yticks1:max(Current_ma));
set(ax(2),'ytick',min(Pos_cts):yticks2:max(Pos_cts));
set (ax(1),'ygrid','on');
set (ax(2),'ygrid','on');
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I would start by checking your tick interval calculation (they might be inadvertently zero).

Comment: Hi gremto, first of all thanks for your help. Theoretically the xticks and yticks are working properly. The number of labels in axes depend of it and work properly, if I modify the values the number of labels also varies. I've tried to set xticks and yticks to a fixed value (ej. 5000) and the number of labels in axes varies as expected but no grid is displayed. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, strange: I've done a small test on Linux (Octave 4.0) and it's working ok for me, which makes me think it's something to do with the input data. Can you post a link to the csv file and I can run here? Longshot- on your plot, is there a checkbox to display/ undisplay gridlines that you can toggle?